# Create dummies when categories are single characters in multi character strings

Tags: python, pandas

Consider my data in a Pandas Series

```
s = pd.Series('1az wb58 jsui ne3'.split())

s

0     1az
1    wb58
2    jsui
3     ne3
dtype: object
```

I need it to look like:

```
   1  3  5  8  a  b  e  i  j  n  s  u  w  z
0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
1  0  0  1  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  0
3  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
```

However when I try:

```
pd.get_dummies(s)

   1az  jsui  ne3  wb58
0    1     0    0     0
1    0     0    0     1
2    0     1    0     0
3    0     0    1     0
```

---

What is the most concise way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe apply `list`

```
pd.get_dummies(s.apply(list).apply(pd.Series).stack()).sum(level=0)
Out[222]: 
   1  3  5  8  a  b  e  i  j  n  s  u  w  z
0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
1  0  0  1  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  0
3  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
```

Or

```
s.apply(list).str.join(',').str.get_dummies(',')
Out[224]: 
   1  3  5  8  a  b  e  i  j  n  s  u  w  z
0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
1  0  0  1  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  0
3  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: `s.apply(list).str.join('|').str.get_dummies()` ?

Comment: You don't need the `apply(list)`.  The string is already an iterable and `s.str.join('|').str.get_dummies()` will do.

Answer (score 2):

Solution with [MultiLabelBinarizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html) and `DataFrame` constructor:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(s),columns=mlb.classes_)
print (df)
   1  3  5  8  a  b  e  i  j  n  s  u  w  z
0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
1  0  0  1  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  0
3  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
```

Another solution - [`DataFrame.from_records`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html) + [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html), but last is necessary aggregate columns by `max`:

```
df = pd.get_dummies(pd.DataFrame.from_records(s),prefix_sep='',prefix='').max(level=0, axis=1)
print (df)
   1  3  5  8  a  b  e  i  j  n  s  u  w  z
0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
1  0  0  1  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  0
3  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
```